# stats latest not showing any value for field

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

We have following query -

```
index=yyy sourcetype=zzz "RAISE_ALERT" logger="aaa" | table uuid message timestamp | eval state="alert" | append [SEARCH index=yyy sourcetype=zzz "CLEAR_ALERT" logger="aaa" | table uuid message timestamp | eval state="no_alert" ] | stats latest(state) as state by uuid
```

But this query is not showing anything for state, it shows only uuid.

[image]

Query before and without latest works just fine. Here is screenshot of result of everything before stats -

[image]

If we replace `stats latest` with `stats first`, we can see uuid and state, its just not the latest observed value of state for that uuid.

Any idea as to why this can happen?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like table clause was the issue. Removing both table clauses makes this work.

Comment: yes - your `|table` was losing the `_time` field, which is necessary for `| stats latest(...)` to work

Comment: also: `| table` is *generally* redundant if run *before* `| stats` because `| stats` will output a table